# how to simplify dataframe with multiple indexes using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4], 'c2':['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b'], 'c3':[25,34,12,14,91,31,52,15]})
df.set_index(['c1','c2'],inplace=True)
df2 = df.unstack('c2')
```

How can I modify `df2` to look like this?

```
c1  a   b
1  25  34
2  12  14
3  91  31
4  52  15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the column level by renaming the columns:

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(level = 0).values
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But what if I wished to keep only 'a' and 'b' as columns and 'c1' as index like in the ideal dataframe in my example? I tried df2.reset_index().set_index('c1'), but it did not work.

Comment: Don't quite get what you mean, in your example, `c1` is already index, you don't need to set it as index separately?